# why volumes not working correctly in docker whene i try to dockerize django app?

Tags: python, django, docker, deployment, devops

The issue arises when I attempt to proceed without using volumes; everything works correctly. However, when volumes are included, I get the following error:

```
django_app  | python: can't open file '/app/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

docker-compose :

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./django:/app // the problem is here
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    image: app:django
    container_name: django_app
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.12.1-slim

 
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

the commands that i use to build and run :

```bash
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

Comment: What commands do you use? Please include them in your question

Comment: Could you please specify the content of your ./django folder ?

Comment: @SCcagg5 this is the folder that i want to data into in another words it not exitst yet , it supose to store every thing from "/app" that in the container in the "/django" folder

Comment: Well, you are starting your app from there, so it should contain your `manage.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I attempt to proceed without using volumes; everything works correctly.

Perfect.  Do that.

More specifically, delete this block:

```yaml
    volumes:
      - ./django:/app // the problem is here
```

This hides everything in the `/app` directory in the image, and replaces it with whatever happens to be in the `django` subdirectory of the directory containing the `docker-compose.yml` file.  If different hosts have different versions of the application checked out, you'll get inconsistent results – this reintroduces the "works on my machine" problem that Docker frequently tries to avoid.

If the Dockerfile does any sort of rearrangement or manipulation of the source file, the bind mount will also hide this.  I've seen Dockerfiles that try to correct DOS line endings or file permissions, for example, and the bind mount will hide those changes.

The more specific disconnect here seems to be that you're `COPY . .` the current directory into `/app` into the image, but then the bind mount hides that and replaces it with a `./django` subdirectory.  Bind-mounting a different subdirectory means that the container filesystem looks totally different from what's in the image.  The `command:` override tries to run the script that's in `./django/manage.py` on the host system.  If the script is actually in the top-level directory, the bind mount hides the copy that's in the image.